# Move applications to SD card

Tags: android

In some apps with min sdk 3 (Android 1.5), I can move application to SD card from my Desire HD.(Android 2.2) How to make it programmatically possibility to move application to SD card with Requires Android 1.5 and up.

Comment: dont forget to mark someone's response as answered by clicking on the checkmark next to the response

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Add android:installLocation="auto" attribute in the  tag of your manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myapp" android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.2">
```

it will enable the Move to SD card button for your application.

Answer (score 30):

You need to include `android:installLocation="auto"` or `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in the `<manifest>` element of your AndroidManifest.xml. You also need to set target API version to Froyo for that (but minimum API version can be lower).

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Answer (score 6):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >

</manifest>
```

For reference check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)